# ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[MessageService -> MessageService -> MessageService]:

Tags: angular

I am converting an old angular 1 to angular 15, in VS code it compiles fine but I am getting this error in browser console. Browser displays a blank page.

I have checked If I need to add MessageService anywhere else in working old code but could not find any reference.

Getting this error in browser console

[image]

App.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { SecurityModule } from "./security/security.module";
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ToastModule } from 'primeng/toast'
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';
import { DialogModule } from 'primeng/dialog'
import { SystemInformationModule } from './system-information/system-information.module';
import { FooterComponent } from './shared/layouts/footer/footer.component';
import { appRouting } from './app-routing.module';
import { HeaderComponent } from './shared/layouts/header/header.component';
import { BodyComponent } from './shared/layouts/body/body.component';
import { MessagesService } from "./shared/services/messages/messages.service";
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BodyComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SecurityModule,
    SystemInformationModule,
    ToastModule,
    ButtonModule,
    DialogModule,
    appRouting
  ],
  providers: [MessagesService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

message.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observer, Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { Message } from "primeng/api";

@Injectable()
export class MessagesService {
  private shortGrowls = new Subject<any>();
  private stickyGrowls = new Subject<any>();
  private socket: Subject<MessageEvent>;

  shortGrowlAdded$ = this.shortGrowls.asObservable();
  stickyGrowlAdded$ = this.stickyGrowls.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  addShortGrowl(message: any) {
    this.shortGrowls.next(message);
  }

  addStickyGrowl(message: any) {
      //console.log(`MessagesService  addStickyGrowl  message: ${JSON.stringify(message)}`);
    this.stickyGrowls.next(message);
  }

  public connect(url: string): Subject<MessageEvent> {
    if (!this.socket) {
      this.socket = this.create(url);
    }

    return this.socket;
  }

  private create(url: string): Subject<MessageEvent> {
    let ws = new WebSocket(url);

    let observable = Observable.create(
      (obs: Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
        ws.onmessage = observable.next.bind(obs);
        ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
        ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);

        return ws.close.bind(ws);
      });

    let observer = {
      next: (data: Object) => {
        if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
          ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
      }
    };

    return Subject.create(observer, observable);
  }

  public addErrorMessages(source: string[]) {
      if (source != undefined && source != null && source.length > 0) {
          source.forEach((msg, i, a) => {
              this.shortGrowls.next({ severity: "error", summary: "Error", detail: msg });
          });
      }
  }

  public getErrorMessageFromResponse(resp: any): Message {
      //Default error message
      var msg: Message = { severity: "error", summary: "Internal Server Error", detail: "Internal Server Error" };

      //console.log(`getErrorMessage from resp: ${JSON.stringify(resp)}`);
      if (resp.statusText != undefined) {
          msg.summary = resp.statusText;
      }

      if (resp._body != undefined) {
          //console.log(`_body != undefined...`);
          try {
              var body = JSON.parse(resp._body);
              if (body.errDetails != undefined) {
                  if (body.errDetails.Message != undefined) {
                      msg.detail = body.errDetails.Message;
                  }
              }
          }
          catch(e) {
          }
      }

      if (resp.errDetails != undefined && resp.errDetails.Message != undefined) {
          msg.detail = resp.errDetails.Message;
      }

      //console.log(`getErrorMessage = ${JSON.stringify(msg)}`);
      return msg;
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```js
// #region imports
import { Component, Output, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

import { Message } from "primeng/api";

import * as DomainModels from "./shared/models/domain";
import { MessagesService } from "./shared/services/messages/messages.service";
import { environment } from "../environments/environment";
import { UserAdGroupService } from "./shared/services/user-ad-groups/user-ad-groups.service";

declare var Ultima: any;
// #endregion

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
  providers: [MessagesService, UserAdGroupService]
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = "MicroScheduler";
    ribbon = environment.ribbon;

    @Output() userId: string;
    @Output() securityGroups: DomainModels.UserAdGroup[] = [];

    public activeMenuId: string;
    public themesVisible = false;
    public mobileMenuActive = false;
    // public shortlivedMessages: Message[] = [];
    // public stickyMessages: Message[] = [];
    public combinedMessages: Message[] = [];
    public showTagMaintenance: boolean = environment.showTagMaintenance;
    public showReports: boolean = environment.showReports;
    public showNetsMock: boolean = environment.showNetsMock;
    public majorVersion: number = environment.majorVersion;
    public release: number = environment.release;
    public componentBuild: number = environment.componentBuild;
    public noAccess: boolean = false;

    constructor( //private usersService: UsersService,
                 private appMessagesService: MessagesService,
                 private userAdGroupService: UserAdGroupService,
                 private el: ElementRef
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.userAdGroupService.list().subscribe(resp => {
                //Handle errors
                if (resp.hasError) {
                    this.appMessagesService.addStickyGrowl(this.appMessagesService.getErrorMessageFromResponse(resp));
                }
                //Display info message if debugging
                if (resp.hasInfoMsg) {
                }

                //Update data
                this.securityGroups = resp.ReturnedItems;

                if (this.securityGroups != undefined && this.securityGroups.length > 0) {
                    this.userId = this.securityGroups[0].UserID;
                }
                else {
                    this.userId = "";
                    this.noAccess = true;
                }

                //this.userId = (this.securityGroups != undefined && this.securityGroups.length > 0) ? this.securityGroups[0].UserID : "";

                return resp;
            },
            response => {
                this.appMessagesService.addShortGrowl(this.appMessagesService.getErrorMessageFromResponse(response));
            }
        );

        this.appMessagesService.shortGrowlAdded$.subscribe(msg => {
            //var newMessages: Message[] = this.shortlivedMessages.concat();
            //newMessages.push(msg);
            msg.key="shortlivedMessages";
            this.combinedMessages.push(msg);
            //this.shortlivedMessages = newMessages;

            //this.shortlivedMessages.push(msg);
        });

        this.appMessagesService.stickyGrowlAdded$.subscribe((msg: Message) => {
            //this.stickyMessages.push(msg);
            msg.key="stickyMessages";
            this.combinedMessages.push(msg);
        });
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        Ultima.init(this.el.nativeElement);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
    }

    toggleMenu(e: any) {
        this.mobileMenuActive = !this.mobileMenuActive;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

VS codes compiles well

[image]

Comment: update this in message.service.ts file @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
}) and try one

Comment: If you read you error its complaining about a messaging service from primeng toast. So you probably looking at the wrong messaging service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You have an issue with primeng component. Check on other components for MessageService of primeng/api package.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the `MessagesService` twice, in `app.module` and `app.component` provider's array.

Usually, when you create a service, that service is available in the entire project, for that, in the service `metadata`, you would require to add `providedIn: 'root'`.

For your case, if you want the service to be used in the entire project, then remove the `MessagesService` from providers and add the following to the service:

**service**

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessagesService {...}
```

**app.module**

```js
  ...
  providers: [], //empty array
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**component**

```js
  ...
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
  providers: [UserAdGroupService] // no MessageService
})
export class AppComponent {
```

If you create a `service` by using the `CLI`, that metadata will be added by default.

Something to keep in mind is that, if you decide to add an specific `service` to the component's `metadata` (in this case `UserAdGroupService`), the data been handled in that service is not going to be available for other components, because, for this case, `app.component` has it's own instance of `UserAdGroupService`.

In other words, if component `A` and `B` has service `C` in their provider's metadata, and `A` passes some data to service `C`, `B` will not be aware of that data, same for the other way around, if `B` passes some data to service `C`, `A` will not known